# Using cell2mat with novalues

Tags: matlab, cell

Using the function `cell2mat` gives me an error when there are NoValues:
`All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.`

The problem is, that in my cellarrays NoValues are not marked as `NaN` but as `#NV`. My idea was to change all `#NV` to `NaN`. But using `strrep(mycell,'#NV','NaN')` gives me the error `Cell elements must be character arrays.`

I could loop through each cellarray and replace the `#NV`, but maybe there is a more neat way to get `double` data from my `cell` data.

Here is an extract how my cellarray (`275449x1 cell`) looks like:

```
'#NV'
'#NV'
0,719302186342827
'#NV'
'#NV'
0,414725728197998
1
1
0,448286010744169
```

If there aren't any `#NV` the function works properly and gives me a `275449x1 double`

Comment: For reference, using `'NaN'` is not the same as using `NaN`. The former is a character array with the characters `'N', 'a', 'N'`, you cannot have this in a numerical matrix. The latter is a numerical type `NaN` which you can have in a matrix and operate on with numerical functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cellfun` to apply a function to each cell.

```
c{1}='#NV';
c{2}=0.719302186342827;
fun=@(mycell)strrep(mycell,'#NV','NaN')
c2=cellfun(fun,c,'UniformOutput',false);
```

> ans =
>
> 1×2 cell array
>
> ```
> 'NaN'    [0.7193]
> ```

However, this is probably not what you are looking, as 'NaN' is now a string, but what you want is a numerical type of `NaN`, which is *not* a string.

I would just easily loop on this:

```
for ii = 1:size(c,1)
   if strcmp(c{ii},'#NV')
       c{ii} = NaN;
   end
end
```

Or, as Adriaan suggest, just:

```
c(strcmp(c,'#NV'))={NaN};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `cellfun` works, but as you already mentioned `cell2mat` still fails, because of the string. I wasn't aware of this.. But I will go with your second suggestion, which I thought wouldn't be very neat, but it's pretty fast. 0,7s in comparison to 47s with `cellfun`. Thanks!

Comment: You don't even need to loop for strcmp, just `iNV=strcmp(c,'#NV');` to give a logical index where #NV occurs and then `c(iNV)={NaN};` to replace them with the NaN

Comment: @Adrian for some reason I though I tried that :/ I need more coffe